# SagePay Form upgrade from 2.23 to 3.00 - Simulated transactions and other issues

Tags: opayo

I've just completed the upgrade from v2.23 to v3.00 and run a successful LIVE transaction, passing `3.00` as the value for `VPSProtocol`.

However, I've been having issues when running SIMULATED transactions using this value as SagePay returns the following error:

`The <b>VPSProtocol</b> field you supplied contains invalid data. It should contain the value <b>2.23</b>`

I'm also still seeing the big red bar at the top of MySagePay with the following scary message:

`You will have to cease trading on this version (v2.23) unless you upgrade by the end of this month.`

So, a couple of questions:

1. Do I need to do anything in MySagePay to tell the system that I'm
   now using v3.00, or will that red bar disappear eventually?
2. Is there a current issue with simulated transactions because the error is still telling me that I need to pass `2.23` as the value for `VPSProtocol` despite this version being dropped?
3. Finally, How do I know that these last transactions I've made while passing `3.00` as the value for `VPSProtocol` have actually been made under v3.00? There's just a lot of confusing things going on here and no clear way to know exactly what's happening (ie, should I be seeing a completely new version of MySagePay somewhere? Or should I be able to distinguish which transactions were made under v2.23 and which were made under v3.00? Etc, etc.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few answers for you:

1. This will disappear eventually if you are processing transactions at 3.00. It seems to behave fairly randomly.
2. You might as well forget about ever using the simulator. It hasn't been updated for protocol 3.00 (and a long time before that).
3. You will be using the current version of MSP, so no worry there. MSP won't actually tell you what protocol a transaction was carried out using, so if you want to be sure, you could make a 'getTransactionDetail' API call. Alternatively, call Sage Pay, give them a TransactionId and get them to confirm the protocol the transaction was processed using.